# How is a universe defined in Battlefield Earth?

Tags: battlefield-earth

I am reading *Battlefield Earth* and they keep referring to there being 16 different universes.

Is there any explanation or indication to what L. Ron Hubbard defines as an universe in the story and how each universe is unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older pulp fiction, the term 'universe' was used interchangeably with 'galaxy'. Even when they knew better, a galaxy was occasionally referred to as an island universe. However, it is clear that Hubbard, by the time he wrote this book, knew the difference, and was using the word 'universe' in the modern sense.

> Jonnie had been amazed to find in other texts that there were four hundred
>   billion suns in this galaxy alone and that this universe contained more than a
>   hundred billion galaxies. And he had sixteen universes to look at.

The different universes have slightly different physical laws.

> Yes, the Psychlos listed radium and even gave it an atomic number of
>   eighty-eight, but they noted it as a rare element. And they had dozens of
>   elements numbered and listed above eighty-eight.
>   Nothing made it plainer than the difference in these tables that he was
>   dealing with an alien planet in an alien universe. Some of the metals were
>   compatible. But on the whole the distribution was different and even atomic
>   formation seemed at variance.

As to the existence of multiple universes, Hubbard gives some vague pseudo-science explanation tied in to the aliens' teleportion technology.

> The mathematics of the text were quite beyond him. They were Psychlo
>   mathematics a long way in advance of what he had studied. The symbols made his
>   head spin.
>
> The history section at the start of the book was perfunctory. It simply stated
>   that a hundred thousand years ago a Psychlo physicist named En had untangled
>   the riddle. Prior to this, it was thought that teleportation consisted of
>   converting energy and matter to space and then reconverting it in another
>   place so it would assume its natural form. But this had never been proven. En
>   had apparently found that space could exist entirely independent of time,
>   energy, or mass and that all these things were actually separate items. Only
>   when combined did they make up a universe.
>
> Space was dependent only upon three coordinates. When one dictated a set of
>   space coordinates one shifted space itself. Any energy or mass contained in
>   that space thereupon shifted with that space shift.
>
> In the matter of a motor such as this freighter had, it was just an enclosed
>   housing in which space coordinates could be changed. As the coordinates
>   changed, the housing was forced to go along, and this gave the motor power.